# How to properly instantiate a Context that have constructors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a question. I have a class like below: I cannot save data to my DB.

```
public class SomeClassContext : DbContext
{ 
    private IConfigurationRoot _configurationRoot;

    public SomeClassContext(DbContextOptions<SomeClassContext> contextOptions, IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot)
    {
        this._configurationRoot = configurationRoot;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configurationRoot["Data:ConnectionString"]);
    }
```

my appsettings.json

```
 {
   "Data": {
      "ConnectionString": "Data Source=MyDataSource;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog",
 }
```

When I'm trying to instantiated SomeClassContext and supplied parameters for the constructor, I'm getting null values

```
public class MyClass
{
    private SomeClassContext context;
    private string _categoryName;
    private Func<string, LogLevel, bool> _filter;

    public MyClass(string categoryName, Func<string, LogLevel, bool> filter)
    {
        _categoryName = categoryName;
        _filter = filter;
        context = new SomeClassContext(//parameters here are required. What should be my parameters here that will not result to null)
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var obj = new MyEntity()
        {
           //assume I have initialize object here
        };
        try
        {
            context.MyEntity.Add(obj);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //debugger throws here
            //cannot save to DB
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include - in your 3rd code block - the actual parameters for the `MyClass` constructor and the `SomeClassContext` constructor? Will make it easier to help you.

Comment: When you use a Dependency Injection container such as that from ASP.NET Core, you don't use the `new` keyword. If you can't change the constructor, you can use the `IServiceLocator` interface which allows you to locate services if they were configured correctly

Comment: Also, you don't normally pass the `IConfigurationRoot` to the context so it can get the connection string, rather, you pass the `DbContextOptionsBuilder` with the `UseSqlServer` function already called from startup

Comment: @urig I edited my question. Camilo I'll research the IServiceLocator thanks